# Scipy Expm for Sparse Matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

So I know I can pass a sparse matrix object into scipy.sparse.linaglg expm, and it returns a spare matrix object as the matrix exponential... but does the actual Pade approximation algorithm that is implemented change whether the variable passed is a  dense or sparse matrix?  I am working on a problem which requires me to calculate the matrix exponential of a very large spare matrix object and I require the Pade approximation for accuracy purposes.

Comment: The documentation of [`scipy.sparse.linalg.expm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.expm.html) says "Compute the matrix exponential using Pade approximation". You can check [the reference paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/09074721X) or [the source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.1/scipy/sparse/linalg/matfuncs.py#L554) for details, but I'm not sure why you should not trust the documentation.

Comment: You can look at the code in `scipy.sparse.linalg.matfuncs._expm`